# How to estimate a probability based on the difference of two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

There are two random variables:

> $X ={}$ the sum of $1,000,000$ real numbers
>   $Y ={}$ the same sum as $X$ with each number rounded to the nearest integer before summing
>
> If the fractions rounded off are independent and each one is **uniformly distributed over $\boldsymbol{(-0.5, 0.5)}$**, use the CLT to estimate the probability that $|X-Y|>700$.

My thought process so far is that $X \thicksim \operatorname{Uni}(-0.5, 0.5)$ and $Y \thicksim \operatorname{Uni}(-1, 1)$, but since $Y$ depends on $X$, what would my actual definition of $Y$ look like? How do I figure out the difference between a uniform and discrete variable?

I think I understand what I am supposed to do once I figure out the correct normal variable to use the CLT on, but I'm just not quite sure how to get there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand: if you're saying that the summands in the definition of $X$ are iid and uniform on $(-1/2,1/2)$, then $Y$ is zero almost surely. I must be missing something. Is the point really just to deal with the sum of 1,000,000 independent variables uniform on $(-1/2,1/2)$, and this whole setup with $X$ and $Y$ is superfluous?

Comment: The problem only makes sense (to me) if the things that are independent and uniform on $(-0.5,0.5)$ are the differences $e_i = y_i -x_i$ (with $X=\sum x_i$, etc) . Is that what you mean? Seriously, you need to make sense of a problem before attempting to solve it.

Comment: The difference $X-Y$ actually computes the sum of fractions rounded off for all your $1,000,000$ numbers. Then you are told each one of those fractions is uniformly distributed over $(-0.5, 0.5)$.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the question, I would set it up like this: we have $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{1000000}$ fixed deterministic numbers, which we sum $X = \sum_{i=1}^{1000000} X_i$, and then we wish to compare that with the sum $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{1000000} Y_i$ is, where $Y_i = \left[ X_i \right]$. We make the modeling assumption that the errors are a random variable $Z_i = Y_i - X_i \sim U(-0.5,0.5)$. Now we want to calculate
$$P(|Y - X| > 700) = P(|\sum_{i=1}^{1000000} Y_i - X_i| > 700)$$
$$= P(|Z| > 700)$$
where $Z$ is a sum of one million uniform random variables and should obey the CLT. From here, we use our knowledge that $Z$ behaves like a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\frac{1000000}{3}$.

Hope that helps.